# The Ultra-Cute Pandas

Tags: wordplay, video-games

It was the late 90’s. I was leaving the theatre having seen my first 3-D film. Suddenly, out of nowhere, a girl appeared from the nearby bushes, demanding I take her money for my 3-D glasses. Slightly stunned, I refused, but she continued to advance, even offering the gemstones around her fingers and neck. Luckily for me, the girl’s best friend appeared, at which point the girl clammed up. I think her friend believed the two of us were acquainted, because she offered to take me along with them to see the new baby pandas at the zoo. I was perplexed, but I thought, “Why not?” We ended up going and saw two *adorable* panda cubs!

**What were the names of the two pandas?**

Comment: The tag is a big hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments on the answers (including mine), I think their names are

> **Sun and Moon**
>
>  The story makes reference to the "main" pairs of games in the Pokémon series, namely:
>  - [**Red and Blue**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Red_and_Blue) lenses in the 3D glasses
>  - [**Gold and Silver**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Gold_and_Silver) money
>  - [**Ruby and Sapphire**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Ruby_and_Sapphire) jewels and gemstones
>  - [**Diamond and Pearl**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Diamond_and_Pearl) via word association: [diamonds are a girl's "best friend"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamonds_Are_a_Girl%27s_Best_Friend), and pearls come from clams ("clammed up")
>  - [**Black and White**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Black_and_White) pandas
>  - [**X and Y**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_X_and_Y) phonemes: "perpl**EX**ed" and "**why** not?"
>
>  The next pair of games is Pokémon [**Sun and Moon**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Sun_and_Moon). These games also came in [Ultra versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Ultra_Sun_and_Ultra_Moon), and the pandas are "ultra-cute."

Comment: Those *are* logical names for pandas, and you're very close. You're missing a couple more clues. [rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)(Gurer ner zber trarengvbaf sbyybjvat Oynpx naq Juvgr.). Don't forget that the title is also a hint!

Comment: Clarification: Whether or not the names are logical/intuitive for pandas is irrelevant.

Comment: Now it’s correct! Technically, you missed the “girl’s best friend” clue, but the answer is detailed enough that I can accept it.

Comment: No, you're right; that's a much better interpretation. I'll edit again.

Answer (score 2):

Are they named

> Red and Blue

3-D glasses

> They traditionally had red-blue anaglyph lenses, specifically for 3-D films in the 90s

The tag is a big hint

> Red vs. Blue was a popular video series based off the Halo videogames

Comment: The names are incorrect, but your remark on the 3-D glasses is crucial.

Answer (score 1):

Are they named

> Pancham and Pangaroo ?

I'm not really sure about how the story fit but I see some keywords:

> Video game tag, 90s, red and blue (3D glasses), gemstone, and only two pandas-like pokemon exist

Comment: You’re on the right track! You’ve got the right **series**. There’s a sequence to it all...

Comment: unfortunately I don't really know rot13(cbxrzba)

Answer (score 0):

Are they:

> Yin and yang? Because pandas are usually black and white and so is yin and yang

Comment: Sorry, good guess, but not the correct direction.

Comment: @CGreen What about now?